# Can a cakephp component use a view

Tags: cakephp, view, components

Can a cakephp component use a view? if yes then please explain how?

Comment: Can you give some more details of why you'd want to do this, or what you'd like to accomplish by having a component use a view? Maybe there's a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

Components in CakePHP do not use views.

You can use component methods in controller actions, and those actions can have views, though.

Answer (score 0):

M - models, behaviors

V - views, elements, helpers

C - controllers, components

things from one group should not be used in the other.